# Adding ActionListener for a typing game

Tags: java, swing, awt, actionlistener, jtextfield

Have been looking at lots of documents about use of `ActionListener` with `JTextField` and have seen a lot of the other questions asked for similar reasons, but I cant seem to apply the solutions to my problem.
The basic premise of what I need is there will be a text field on the screen for the user to type words into.

I want a timer to start running in the background after a certain key press. (preferably enter or spacebar) and then the timer should stop when the entire sentence has been written. So far I have not had much luck with getting an event to start with a key press. Below is some code that doesn't really work, I can successfully create the frame with the text box I just can't get the action listener to work for the purpose I want it for.

```
input = new JTextField();
input.setBounds(10, 150, 780, 35);
panel.add(input);
input.addActionListener(new ActionListener());

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
}
```

Haven't added anything in the `actionPerformed` method as all the tests I ran weren't successful. Not asking for full code but a pointer in the right direction could help. Yes I have read the docs on how to use [`addActionListener()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html#addActionListener(java.awt.event.ActionListener)) but I can't apply it to what I want to do.

Comment: For a [JTextField](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html) the [ActionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) is invoked when the user presses <ENTER> when the `JTextField` has keyboard [focus](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html). Do you want to measure the time it takes for the user to enter a sentence into the `JTextField`? How will you know when _the entire sentance has been written_ ?

Comment: @Abra was simply going to tell the user to press enter once they have finished the sentence. Im having a lot more luck with the KeyListener that Ryan suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a KeyListener, not an ActionListener.

Comment: Will look into KeyListener once ive finished eating thank you

Answer (score 0):

Implement KeyListener, and then in the method keyPressed(KeyEvent name),
type e.getKeyCode using either a `switch` or `if` statement.
eg(pseudo code):

```
 javax.swing.JTextField input=null;
 javax.swing.JPanel panel=null;
 public class X implements java.awt.event.KeyListener{

 input = new javax.swing.JTextField();
 input.setBounds(10, 150, 780, 35);

 panel.add(input);
 input.addActionListener(new ActionListener());
 input.addKeyListener(this);
 public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent e){
 if(e.getKeyCode==e.VK_W){
 //Enter code here 
 }}public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
 //then upon enter the timer stops
 }


 }
```